# why can g++ not have variable length array initialization

Tags: c++, c++11, g++

I am using C++ 11 and this is an example code fragment where I am not able to understand the internal workings of the language.

This works -

```
int main(){
int n;
cin>>n;
int a[n]; // THIS WORKS due the the extensions
```

However, this does **not** work -

```
int main(){
int n;
cin>>n;
int a[n] = {0} // This does not work;
```

I am compiling this using:

```
g++ -std=c++0x file.cpp -o file
```

1. I understand that VLA's are not part of the C++ standard and the GNU C++ provides it via compiler extensions.
2. I also understand that the memory is allocated at runtime using *alloca*.
3. What I don't understand is that, if A works, why can B not work?

Comment: B clearly can be made to work. But the gcc people didn't for whatever reason. I don't think tracking down who thought "good enough" is worthwhile.

Comment: It isn't legal in C either, and the extension is in large part there for compatibility with C. Actually, g++ (since 4.9) accepts your code here, what do you mean by "does not work"?

Comment: What behaviour is expected if the length of the initializer != the length of the array?

Comment: @Marc, B gives a compile time error - "a may not have been initialized"

Comment: The behavior seems likely to change soon: https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2017-03/msg01487.html